# MySQL Performance Schema

Tags: mysql, performance

My company hosts a mysql database on google and we do not have complete control over the customization involved. Recently we attempted to turn performance schema on to help debug some common complaints about our software. During the restart that was required after adjusting the flag the database was continually failing to start which caused massive problems with our customers as you can imagine.

At this point it looks like performance schema and everything that falls under its umbrella is essentially out of the question. Are there any other tools or ways to analyze a mysql database if the performance schema features are inaccessible? Aside from looking at the execution plan of every query manually.

Comment: This question _might_ be better suited at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @WilliamIsted Good call, I'll ask it over there.

Comment: Please provide the link to the SE question.

Comment: [DBA Stack Exchange question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164292/mysql-performance-schema/164489)